# Unable to find name from Select List using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium

I am trying to find the option value "Select Account". The Html code behind the page is:

```
<tbody>
<tr class="alt first">
<tr>
<td height="30">
<select id="pkitem" name="pkitem" size="1" class="selectfont"    onchange="multipickvalue(document.formMain.pkitem,document.formMain.listdata);document.formMain.listmodified.value=1;">
<option value="">--- Select Account---</option>
<option value="**COPY" size="small">*PRIVATE AND CONFIDENTIAL* CON  (**COPY)  </option>
<option value="ALDWYCH" size="small">*PRIVATE AND CONFIDENTIAL* CON  (ALDWYCH)</option>
<option value="56456465456456456" size="small">12345  (56456465456456456)</option>
<option value="12345" size="small">123456  (12345)</option>
<option value="2SISTERGRP" size="small">2 SISTERS FOOD GROUP  (2SISTERGRP)</option>
<option value="402SIST12" size="small">2 SISTERS FOOD GROUP  (402SIST12)</option>
```

The C# code that I am using is:

```
var SelectAcc1 = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.Id("pkitem"));
var SelectElement = new SelectElement(SelectAcc1);
SelectElement.SelectByText(SelectAcc);
```

It is unable to find the Field name. Can someone please help.

Comment: What is the value of `SelectAcc`?

Comment: can you please properly indent your HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, we can't find Text 'SelectAcc' on your HTML code.

Second, you didn't use `Select` class of Selenium framework which helps to work on Select list.

Third, even if you had initialised the `Select` class some where in your code, but the `Select` class doesn't have any method by `SelectByText` name.

Fourth, the way of passing value is incorrect, it expect a String value so it should be in double quote i.e. it should be like

```
selectByVisibleText("123456  (12345)");
```

Refer [SELECT CLASS](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)

There are 3 ways to select value from Select list.
 1. selectByIndex
 2. selectByValue
 3. selectByVisibleText

Comment: Hi Gaurav, SelectAcc is the name of the string which is holding the value ""123456  (12345)" in this case. It is already mentioned in the C# code, its not something to worry about. My main concern is getting the field name here which is pkitem.

Answer (score 0):

To find the element, either Find the Element using Xpath or get the options from SelectElement matching that the `value` attribute is `String.Empty`

```
IWebElement SelectAccount = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(@"//select[@id='pkitem']/option[@value='']"));
```

or

```
IWebElement SelectAcc1 = driver.FindElement(By.Id("pkitem"));
SelectElement selectElement = new SelectElement(SelectAcc1);
IWebElement SelectAccount = selectElement.Options.FirstOrDefault(o => o.GetAttribute("value").Equals(string.Empty));
// This approach is slower than the first one
```